Google Places Autocomplete API limit to residential address
Is there a way to limit google places autocomplete type to just, home address, condominium, flat, apartment or residential building? (for property listing)
Looking at the Place Types in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types
does not seem to be an option for that. Or if there is any combination I can use so that I can get my desired result?
To have autocomplete to just return residential building or address.

Might be able to implement with the AutoCompleteService by examining the types of the predictions.  The issue is going to be that for businesses there are usually 2 entries, one for the postal address (which doesn't include any details about the business) and one for the business itself, so it is not to hard to just get businesses, but will be hard to get addresses that aren't businesses.
